# Behavior of transient states as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, asymptotics, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a discrete time-homogeneous Markov chain on the state space $E$. Suppose $T \subseteq E$ is the set of transient states.

Can it be that we stay forever in $T$, with positive probability?

If yes, how can it be that $P_y[X_n=x] \rightarrow 0$ for all $x \in T, y \in E$?

If no, how can one see this intuitively? Couldn't it be that there is an infinite set of transient states, each of the transient states not visited infinitely often, but nevertheless the markov chain always stays within $T$?

Comment: If the chain stays forever in $T$ then there must be states in $T$ which are visited i.o. So, $T$ cannot be transient...

Comment: Couldn't it be that there are "more" states in $T$ than the chain spends time in it? I know it somehow sounds strange, but I am a bit confused about it.

Comment: I am not completely sure about your example, as we have that all states are transient, so it will always be at a transient state then, so actually the set of transient states is never left. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not. Consider a simple random walk on $E=\mathbb{Z}^3$. Then all states are transient, i.e. $T=E$, and naturally the random walk never leaves $T$.

Now, there is a theorem that says that in the above settings, and for any two states $x,y$, we have 
$$
\mathbb{P}_x[X_n=y] \leq \mathbb{P}_x[X_n=x].
$$
And since $x$ is a transient state, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}_x[X_n=x]=0$.

I hope this clarifies the picture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I am even more confused. So you say what d.k.o. says is wrong? How can it be that the probability of all transient states is 0 whereas obviously $\sum_{y \in E} \mathbb{P}_x[X_n=y]=1$ for all $n \geq 1$?

Comment: And also, we have stated that for a transient state we have that the time of the last visit is almost surely finite. Doesn't this contradict your statement?

Comment: I think that d.k.o. had *finite* state space in mind. For infinite state spaces what he/she wrote is not true, see again the example of $\mathbb{Z}^3$.
In the equation you wrote, $n$ does not go to infinity, so I don't see what it would present a contradiction.
Why would finite time of last visit would present a contradiction on an infinite state space?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To summarize: It can be that we stay with positive probability (or even probability 1) always in a transient class. But each transient state is only visited finitely often, in particular there is a last visit time? Moreover, for finite $n$ there is always a state visited (in particular, if all states are transient, then one of the transient states is visited with probability 1) at point $n$ but for $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have that none of the transient states is visited? These strange things occur if $E$ is infinite. Is this correct?

Comment: If the state space is finite, however, we have to leave $T$ at some point and never return. So it cannot be that we stay with positive probability in a finite transient set? Then we almost surely leave it in finite time to go to a recurrent class, in which we stay forever.

Comment: Yep, you are correct

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. THat helped a lot!

Comment: This is not true: $\mathbb{P}_x[X_n=y] \leq \mathbb{P}_x[X_n=x].$

Comment: (only for even times, of course)

Comment: I thought I would understand it, but now this confuses me: 
We prove that if $|E|< \infty$, then there must be a positive recurrent state (or even all states must be positive recurrent). In order to do that, we assume that all states are null recurrent, hence $\mathbb{P}_y[X_n=x] \rightarrow 0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$ for all $x,y \in E$, and therefore $\sum_{x \in E}\mathbb{P}_y[X_n=x] \rightarrow 0$, whereas $\sum_{x \in E} \mathbb{P}[X_n=x]=1$ for all $n,y$. I thought one is in one state with probability 1 for finite $n$ but in the limit one need not be, how is this a contradiction then?

Answer (score 2):

*Another simple example:*

Consider a random walk on the real line with $p=1$ of a jump to the right. Then we have an infinite number of open classes, no closed classes, and all states are transient. Naturally, then, we stay within the set of transient states.

Comment: +1 A trivial but handy example. By the way, I guess the state space as a whole is a closed class.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland That's true actually, thanks! And yes, I recall once getting asked OP's near exact question on an exam, I was incredibly relieved to know this example.